# Visual Source Safe on VB. 6.0 strange message on other machine

Tags: vb6

is there anyone here who can help me with my problem,

we are 3 programmers enhancing an existing system. we agreed that we must have a source control to easily see what are the changes happen on the forms and modules we've modified,

and thanks to visual source safe built in vb 6.0

now, something strange appear. so were done creating the source control, we have  a host machine where and share the database folder.

on the first and second machine, it successfully run, the two machine has the connection to the host server, but on the third, I don't know why but every time he open the file using source control, it has ( I don't know if that is a error)a  message  "Failed to reload the project, please close this project from the file menu and re-open  it to get the correct version on the file loaded into memory.

but we do same as procedure on 1st and 2nd.

we do what the message say but nothing happen.

is there anyone could help me/us..

Comment: Are you sure that the system and settings are _identical_ on each machine?

Comment: I know that this won't help this question - but I strongly recommend you use something like Subversion or git. We moved away from SourceSafe ages ago - it's untrustworthy.

Comment: I've been using source safe for about 15 years now.  Never had a problem.  The problem you are experiencing is probably because of differences in your versions of various supporting dll's and ocx's.  I would suggest you open the .vbp file in notepad and inspect the contents.  Many of the lines will reference various controls.  Make sure that all three of the computers have the same controls and the same version of the controls.